# What type of data should be passed from Angular 2 which matches type HttpPostedFileBase type in Asp Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I have a HTML code which ask for an upload of image file:

```
 <input (change)="onSubmit($event)"  type="file" ... .... accept="image/*" /> //Assume the correct bindings for value
```

And the value/path is stored in a string variable named `path` in corresponding ts file. The value of `path` variable is then sent to api controller's post method:

```
@Component({
   ...
   ...
})

export class UpdateProduct implements OnInit {
      path:string;

      onSubmit(form){
          this.path=form.target.value;
          //logic for http post-I am sending the value to api controller
        }
    }
```

My api controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(ProductUpdates))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostProductUpdates(string path)
    {
    }
```

I want to retrieve the image and store in a temp folder here. For the same I searched on internet and found this piece of code:

```
var FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
            var map=Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Image Database")); //My temp folder
            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(map, FileName));
```

where object `file` is the object of HTTPPostedFileBase. Here I get null reference exception since there is no value provided to it.

Having quoted the scenario, here are **my questions**:

1. Is my approach correct to upload an image and send its path to api controller for retrieving the image and saving it in temp folder? (Since browsers allots fakepaths)
2. Is there any datatype to save blob, HTTPPostedFileBase or file type variables in angular 2?
3. What is the simplest way to store image in temp folder whose client side is written in Angular 2 and server side is linked with api controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Is my approach correct to upload an image and send its path to api controller for retrieving the image and saving it in temp folder?  - wrong. The path which client uploads will not be available in server. Say, Im uploading file from my drive D:\MyFiles\test.png , you cant expect this path in your server
2. Is there any datatype to save blob, HTTPPostedFileBase or file type variables in angular 2? - You can POST file using FormData which then you could receive in HttpPostedFileBase parameter in your api action.

When you Post FormData from angular, make sure you set content-type header to undefined and use the same property name in formdata as well as in api action.

**Update - Adding code**

WebApi

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AjaxUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{ ........... }
```

Html

AngularJs

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", your_image_data_which_would_be_element.files[0]);
```

Angular Service:

```
        return $http.post(baseUrl, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        });
```